# Dynamically filling a JComboBox when it's used as a table editor

Tags: java, swing, jtable

I have a use case (in Java Swing) where a certain `JTable` column must be editable via a `JComboBox` editor, but the list of values that are selectable depend on the domain object for the row (I'm using a custom `TableModel`).

The `CellEditor` interface has events to be called when editing is stopped or cancelled, but no event that editing has started (which I would expect to be a good place to fill my list of selection values).

How can I fill the combo box when editing starts for a cell?

Comment: I ended up overriding JTable's prepareEditor method, but the accepted answer is the more elegant way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a problem, that i had to solve earlier this year (the code below is from that project). The solution was to create a dedicated model for the combobox:

```
mEntityListModel = getMyEntityModel();

T[] items = (T[]) Array.newInstance(type, mEntityListModel.getSize());

for (int i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
    items[i] = mEntityListModel.getElementAt(i);
}
mComboBoxModel = new DefaultComboBoxModel<T>(items);
```

and equalise every change from the entity list with the combobox model:

```
mEntityListModel.addListDataListener(new DataListener());// make a better MVC solution if you like

private class DataListener implements ListDataListener {

    @Override
    public void intervalAdded(ListDataEvent e) {
        mComboBoxModel.insertElementAt(mEntityListModel.getElementAt(e.getIndex0()), e.getIndex0());
    }

    @Override
    public void intervalRemoved(ListDataEvent e) {
        Object deletedElement = mComboBoxModel.getElementAt(e.getIndex0());

        // Clear the combobox selection, if the item is deleted!
        if (mSelectionManager.isSelected(deletedElement)) {
            mSelectionManager.setSelectedItem(null);
        }
        mComboBoxModel.removeElementAt(e.getIndex0());
    }

    @Override
    public void contentsChanged(ListDataEvent e) {
        intervalRemoved(e);
        intervalAdded(e);
    }

}
```

*Sidenote:* This is how changes in the table's combobox are registered:

```
tablecolumn.getCellEditor()
           .addCellEditorListener(new CellChangeListener());


private class CellChangeListener implements CellEditorListener {

    @Override
    public void editingStopped(ChangeEvent e) {
        DefaultCellEditor editor;
        Object newValue;
        if (e.getSource() instanceof DefaultCellEditor) {
            editor = (DefaultCellEditor) e.getSource();

            newValue = editor.getCellEditorValue();

            if (newValue != null) {
                //set the newValue for the combobox selection manager
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void editingCanceled(ChangeEvent e) {
    }
}
```

As you can see, the combobox item list is updated before the editor begins it's work. The editor is not responsible for that job.

Answer (score 1):

What items are available in the ComboBox is responsability of its model. Customize your [ComboBoxModel](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/ComboBoxModel.html) (particularly the `getElementAt(int)` method)so that it consults the domain object in question.

You might want to extend `DefaultComboBoxModel` instead of implementing the interface from scratch.

Answer (score 1):

One way is to override the `getCellEditor(...)` method of JTable:

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.border.*;
import javax.swing.table.*;

public class TableComboBoxByRow extends JPanel
{
    List<String[]> editorData = new ArrayList<String[]>(3);

    public TableComboBoxByRow()
    {
        setLayout( new BorderLayout() );

        // Create the editorData to be used for each row

        editorData.add( new String[]{ "Red", "Blue", "Green" } );
        editorData.add( new String[]{ "Circle", "Square", "Triangle" } );
        editorData.add( new String[]{ "Apple", "Orange", "Banana" } );

        //  Create the table with default data

        Object[][] data =
        {
            {"Color", "Red"},
            {"Shape", "Square"},
            {"Fruit", "Banana"},
            {"Plain", "Text"}
        };
        String[] columnNames = {"Type","Value"};

        DefaultTableModel model = new DefaultTableModel(data, columnNames);
        JTable table = new JTable(model)
        {
            //  Determine editor to be used by row
            public TableCellEditor getCellEditor(int row, int column)
            {
                int modelColumn = convertColumnIndexToModel( column );

                if (modelColumn == 1 && row < 3)
                {
                    JComboBox<String> comboBox1 = new JComboBox<String>( editorData.get(row));
                    return new DefaultCellEditor( comboBox1 );
                }
                else
                    return super.getCellEditor(row, column);
            }
        };

        JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane( table );
        add( scrollPane );
    }

    private static void createAndShowUI()
    {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Table Combo Box by Row");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.add( new TableComboBoxByRow() );
        frame.setSize(200, 200);
        frame.setLocationByPlatform( true );
        frame.setVisible( true );
    }

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable()
        {
            public void run()
            {
                createAndShowUI();
            }
        });
    }
}
```